# Wifi getting disconnecting randomly on asus laptop (Ubuntu version 18.04.1 ; kernel: 4.15.0-43)

Tags: wireless, kernel, asus

Wifi connection randomly gets disconnected and may be due to same problem laptop gets freeze. I have tried all the solutions available on the internet.
On running `iwconfig` I get:

[image: Output of iwconfig]

on running `journalctl --follow` I get:

[image: journalctl --follow output]

I followed [this thread about a similar issue on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298681&page=3) but nothing worked.

Comment: Your output smells like a possible hardware problem. Random freezes tend to make me look toward bad RAM (look up how to run MEMTEST) or a motherboard issue (Update your BIOS, check mfr support). Try an 18.10 LiveUSB to see if any (fixed) software bugs might be responsible.

Comment: I checked my ram using memory test option in live mode. There is no problem. But while bootingliveUSB it shows error "please update microkernel to 25 or up. When I execute commands to update microkernel, it outputs that latest microkernel already installed.

Comment: I feel there is problem in wifi either software or hardware. When I turn off wifi system,  behaves properly and many times Ubuntu is not able to find wifi adaptor. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Please help i have updated bios and kernel. Then to I am still facing wifi adaptor problem.